# While raising the accelerator suddenly my bike's speed goes down

Tags: motorcycle, carburetor, yamaha, acceleration

While driving, I faced some problem in my bike. when `I raise the accelerator suddenly my bike's speed goes down`. Anyone knows what is the problem?. I'm using `yamaha ss 125 cc` bike.

Comment: Are you still having this problem?

Comment: For me, the actual reason is bike clutch plate and it's wiring fault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a carburated engine (not fuel injection) then it's likely that one or more of your carburettor jets is blocked or the diaphragm has a hole in it. Find a service manual for this motorcycle (there's probably a PDF of it somewhere on the internet) and follow the instructions for taking the top off the carb, you will need screwdrivers, small spanners or a socket set and a spray can of carb cleaner that comes with a straw. You'll probably have to take the fuel tank off to get the top off the carb. If you can't find carb cleaner, a spray can of WD40 will work.

Once you've taken the top off the carb (watch out for the spring and don't lose the little clip on the needle) you need check for pinholes in the diaphragm and clean the jets (all the little holes in the bottom of the carb including the one that the needle goes in and the one with a small pin coming out of it, nearest to the engine) by pressing the straw into the hole (with the other end connected to the spray can, in case you don't realise) and spraying the cleaner into it. Forcing the cleaner into the jets like that helps to blast all the goo out.
If the diaphragm has a pinhole in it, you can use a tiny blob of glue (or instant gasket) to seal it but the blob must be as small as possible otherwise the diaphragm won't work properly and the engine still won't run properly.

Also, try Bradshaw's suggestion for adjusting the idle jet aka air screw.

Answer (score 3):

Twisting the throttle opens the butterfly valve in the carburetor which allows it to suck in more air.  With the increased air flow, the carb *should* also suck in more fuel.  So, if enough fuel isn't supplied the engine can't handle the extra air.  I don't know enough about your bike to offer a solution, but this is one possible cause.

Answer (score 2):

Screw in your air screw which is the small one next to the idol screw. And then turn out 2 and a half turns, should bring it back to stock and then you can adjust it from there and then find the sweet spot.

Answer (score 0):

It's 90%problem with the ignition coil.
Change the coil first then look in for wiring clips loose connection. Petroleum filters. Finally check for carborator.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you qualify your suggestions by explaining how these could be the cause for the troubles faced by the OP?

Answer (score 0):

it sounds to me like it is being flooded slowly

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! To really make this an answer, explain to the OP why this might be the problem, then explain how to check to see if it is the problem and maybe how to go about fixing it. Detailed answers go a long way around here and are very much appreciated!